# Embedded for loop can't access the variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop

My code have the problem of embedded for loop can't access the variables. I am using C#. Here is the codes:

```
<%  List<ProductPacking> categoryList = new List<ProductPacking>();
                    categoryList = packBLL.getAllCategory();
                    foreach(ProductPacking cl in categoryList) { %>

                <!-- FIRST COLLAPSIBLE PANEL EXTENDER -->
                <asp:Panel ID="pHeader1" runat="server" CssClass="cpHeader">
                    <!-- First collapsible panel extender header -->
                    <div class="form-group" style="background-color: #ffb848; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div style="float: left; color: White; padding: 5px 5px 0 0">
                                <%= cl.categoryName; %>
                            </div>
```

However, at this line: `<%= cl.categoryName; %>`, it told me the name cl does not exist in current context. I wonder why is it so.

Comment: I believe inline ASP code scope is quite restricted. Also, this looks like it might be a good case for an ASP Repeater: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is the way of how you are closing the tags in this case is the for each ends before the elements you want to render, try to close that at the end of the html to display and avoid using asp tags as well.

try something like

```
<% 
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   List<ProductPacking> categoryList = new List<ProductPacking>();
   categoryList = packBLL.getAllCategory();
   foreach(ProductPacking cl in categoryList) { 
       sb.AppendFormat("<div>{0}</div>",cl.categoryName);
       //some more html here
   }
   response.write(sb.ToString());
%>
```

but I'd prefer to use a grid or another similar control and customize the row template to make my life easier

Comment: I think I will be using repeater and collapsible panel extender to do this. Thanks for the effort tho.